# Azure Functions - BlobTrigger - How to trigger function with any file in a container?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, event-driven

I'm facing a problem with an Azure Function.

I've build an Azure Function triggered by a new file on a container of a storage account.
The problem is that it seems impossible (to me) to trigger the function with a generic file, without specifing a name!

I've searched on official documentation and it's not specified how to reference a generic file. The expected behaviour is to have a function triggered when I upload any file (with any name) in a specific container, something like "container/*".

This is my simple function:

**function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "premium-input/*",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

****init**.py**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(inputBlob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info("START EXECUTION")
    logging.info(f'NAME {inputBlob.name}')
    logging.info(f'URI {inputBlob.uri}')
    logging.info("END EXECUTION")
```

I've already tried using an event on EventGrid, but I prefer avoiding it...

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: As currently configured it should be triggered when a blob is uploaded to the `premium-input` container in the specified storage account

Comment: Have you tried to set the path to "path": "premium-input/{name}". I didn't find any documentation which says to set it to /*.

Comment: @PeterBons This would be the expected behavious, but this is actually the problem: with the configuration above the function is never triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to upload generic files to a container as below and my function got triggered. If you will change the path `premium-input/*` to `premium-input/{name}` , it will work.

****init**.py**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
f"URI: {myblob.uri}\n"
f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

**function.json**

```
{
"bindings": [
{
"name": "myblob",
"type": "blobTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"path": "demo/{name}",
"connection": "your connection string"
}
]
}
```

**Container**-
[image]

**Logs**-
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I had another problem that masked the correct behaviour, the Log Stream didn't update. Thanks!